# highcharts: adding a submit button inside a Highchart's column

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to put a submit button in the second column of this tabular chart so each of 2 rows ("Location one" and "Location two") has one. How is the best to do this please?

[JS fiddle demo][1]
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/Josko_Zadar/L39suv5d/47

Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button in every place you want using **Highcharts.SVGRenderer**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }]
}, function(chart) {
  chart.renderer.button('Button', 200, 100)
    .attr({
      zIndex: 3
    })
    .on('click', function() {
      alert('Hello')
    })
    .add();
});
```

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#button

**Simplified demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yrpsqzb0/

Comment: Thank You very much for showing a good direction!!!
Nevertheless as You can see in my updated JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Josko_Zadar/L39suv5d/54/

I succeeded to add a button per each series' row but buttons' column-position seems to be fixed (absolute). Because my chart adds columns dynamically for each series inside a loop (connecting "yAxis" parameter with "yAxisId" variable), is there a way to assign such relative position to a button same way as other series' columns already are ?
Many thanks!!

Comment: Any idea regarding this absolute positioning?

Comment: Apologize for the late response! The load() event is triggered only when the chart is finished loading. If you want to have pinned button to the relevant position, you need to catch the position each time when the chart is resizing. To achieve that, use the render() event. Take a look at this simplified example, when the button is pinned to the point: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t6gfdszp/. Feel free to ask any other questions if something is not clear!